# Running two versions of MongoDB assemblies at the same time

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-assembly

All,

My Project - (VS 2010 / .NET 4 / ASP.NET application, my web application lives inside Sitefinity as a Sitefinity application)

I have two versions of the MongoDB assemblies. I would like to run these side-by-side in my web application. Here's my setup:

```
\bin\AuxFiles\[1.8.3.9] assemblies

\bin\[1.4.x.x] assemblies
```

Web config:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MongoDB.Bson" publicKeyToken="f686731cfb9cc103" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="1.4.2.4500" href="bin\MongoDB.Bson.dll" />
    <codeBase version="1.8.3.9" href="bin\AuxFiles\MongoDB.Bson.dll" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MongoDB.Driver" publicKeyToken="f686731cfb9cc103" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="1.4.2.4500" href="bin\MongoDB.Driver.dll" />
    <codeBase version="1.8.3.9" href="bin\AuxFiles\MongoDB.Driver.dll" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

When the application starts, it loads the 1.4.x.x assemblies by default. When I go to the page that uses the 1.8.3.9 version of assemblies I get an error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.8.3.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.8.3.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: ....


 Source File:  ......   Line:  18 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.8.3.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103' could not be loaded.



=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.8.3.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/DEV/Visual Studio 2010/WebStoreApp/WebStoreApp/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\DEV\Visual Studio 2010\WebStoreApp\WebStoreApp\bin
   ===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\DEV\Visual Studio 2010\WebStoreApp\WebStoreApp\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.8.3.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/d73c4379/cb2aee95/MongoDB.Driver.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/d73c4379/cb2aee95/MongoDB.Driver/MongoDB.Driver.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/DEV/Visual Studio 2010/WebStoreApp/WebStoreApp/bin/MongoDB.Driver.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.



Stack Trace: 



[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.8.3.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
        System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint
```

---

**UPDATE 1**:

I have tried to rename my new 1.8.x.x assemblies from `MongoDB.Driver.dll` to `MongoDB.Driver.exe` so the files can co-exist under same directory (the older assemblies have extension `.dll`, the new version of the assemblies have extension `.exe`) but the loader seems not to pickup the assemblies. My understanding is that the loader always tries `.dll`s first, then tries `.exe`s second. I am a bit puzzled.

---

**UPDATE 2**:

I have created a console application w/ exactly identical setup of my dual references and the app config entries that you see here,- and the application works, it executes 2 versions of the Mongo dll. The question is now, why doesn't this setup work in my Web application? Are my directories wrong? If you look below at the probing for the assemblies, it never checks my AuxFiles directory, it appears it simply ignores my configuration for side-by-side execution in `web.config`.

```
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/d73c4379/cb2aee95/MongoDB.Driver.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/d73c4379/cb2aee95/MongoDB.Driver/MongoDB.Driver.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/DEV/Visual Studio 2010/WebStoreApp/WebStoreApp/bin/MongoDB.Driver.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

---

**UPDATE 3**:

Found the issue but I am not sure of the details of this solution. The web.config file has `'configuration'` root element w/ the following namespace declaration - `'xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0'`.

The root element is fine but the specified namespace is causing my `'runtime'` element to be ignored. Removing the namespace from the configuration element fixes everything.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the term *side-by-side assembly*. It does *not* mean that you can load *two versions* of the same DLL *into the same execution context*.

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to run two different drivers?

Comment: According to "Applied MS .net Framework" by Jeffrey Richter, he states that you can load 2 versions of the same DLL.

Comment: I am running two versions because the code I am working w/ uses an older version but I need to use a newer version.

Comment: Here's the statement from the book "Applied MS .net Framework" by Jeffrey Richter about side-by-side execution: The CLR has the ability to load multiple files with the same name but with different paths into a single address space. This is called side-by-side execution ...

Comment: Example what I am trying to get working: http://ilearnable.net/2010/08/27/running-two-versions-of-nhibernate-side-by-side/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue:

The 'configuration' root element in the web.config file contains the following namespace declaration - 'xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0'. Removing the namespace from the configuration element fixes everything.

Why the ns? It is more of a bug then anything in VS and has really no real purpose but mess up your intellisense and in my case the runtime configuration. Read more about it:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/02/432077.aspx